# VBA- Retrieving data from an access database by referencing a column in excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I am not able to run the  for loop when number of rows exceed 8-9k.
Can you suggest an alternate method for this? can you suggest the syntax to referencing the data using a tablename(or column name) instead of looping over the cells one by one?

```
Sub ddd()
Const dbloc As String = "C:\Users\system1\Downloads\Database11.accdb"
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim xlbook As Workbook
Dim xlsheet As Worksheet
Dim a As Long
Dim SQL As String


Set xlbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set xlsheet = xlbook.Worksheets(1)
xlsheet.Range("B2:Z100000").ClearContents


Set db = OpenDatabase(dbloc)

SQL = "SELECT Material, MPN  "
SQL = SQL & "FROM Sheet2 "

  SQL = SQL & "WHERE Material IN ("
  Dim r As Range
  For Each r In Range("A2:A6768")
   SQL = SQL & r.Text & ","
  Next r
  SQL = Left(SQL, Len(SQL) - 1) 'Drop last comma
  SQL = SQL & ")"



Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
MsgBox "No data retrieved from database", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "No         
 Data"
    GoTo SubExit
Else
    rs.MoveLast
    recCount = rs.RecordCount
    rs.MoveFirst
End If
 xlsheet.Range("C2").CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

Comment: When you say, "I am not able to run ...", do you mean that the code doesn't work in those cases?  If so, it's broken, and not yet ready for review.  We only consider **working** code here.

Comment: How many records total in the table being queried?

Comment: around 100k max

Comment: In that case you could query the whole table and load the data into a dictionary keyed on Material.  Then pull A2:A6768 into an array and loop over it, looking up each value against the dictionary and putting the result into a same-sized array which you can finally dump back on the worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that instead of building such a large `WHERE` clause dynamically, and running into the 64K character limitation of a query's text, that you create a table and insert into it the data from Excel. Your SQL then becomes:

```
SELECT Sheet2.Material, Sheet2.MPN
FROM Sheet2 
INNER JOIN TempSelection
  ON Sheet2.Material = TempSelection.Material
```

which will work with large amount of selection.

To achieve this, you should create the table `TempSelection` in Access - it only needs one column, `Material` of the same data type as the `Sheet2` table (is that a linked table to Excel or an actual Access table that was imported from Excel? If imported, good; otherwise, I encourage you to import data instead).

Then your `For...Next` loop would now look similar to this...

```
db.Execute "DELETE FROM TempSelection;", dbFailOnError
Set rsTemp = db.OpenRecordset("TempSelection", dbOpenDynaset)
For Each r In Range("A2:A6768")
  rsTemp.AddNew
  rsTemp.Fields("Material").Value = r.Value2 'Or, r.Value if needed
  rsTemp.Update
Next r
```

Answer (score 0):

For review, ignoring the excessive SQL selection, I would observe that your code is quite likely to create a spreadsheet of misaligned and partial data. Any values requested for retrieval which don't actually exist in the database or are in a different order than the spreadsheet will be set against a different identifier, potentially wrecking any association with the values in the A column.

If that association is not important, I would suggest that the records should be put into a different tab (or different workbook altogether).

If the association with the A column is wanted, you could retrieve the records singly, although of course that would take more time. The gaps of nonexistent records would be apparent, if that might be useful.

You can achieve the sheet clearing action you seem to want at the start of the process - preserving first row and first column - more generally with `xlsheet.UsedRange.Offset(1,1).ClearContents`